# getJSON dosen't work on IE during typing special characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, getjson

I am using `$.getJSON` to autocomplete control and everything is fine for chrome browser. 
On IE, only plain text (without special characters like 'ż','ł' etc.) work fine.

Probbably it is cause by encoding but I don't know in which place I should do something. I tried to do this on controller which return JSON object, in javascript (`$.ajaxSetup`), on Layout (meta charset in head section) but result was the same.

Where I done mistake ?

Comment: Can you describe what the problem looks or acts like?  You've only said it works with one browser and not another.  Are there additional symptoms you can share?

Comment: Have you tried Javascripts Encode and Decode functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wesley Skeen - thanks for advice.

I used encodeURI on Url pass to getJSON:

I paste solution, maybe it will be helpful for someone.

`$.getJSON(encodeURI("@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?parameter="+valueOfParameter),function(data){ .... });`